# Afnetworking throwing error in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

Hello Friends I am stuck with my project. I am using AFNETWORKING for API hitting. I used some code for timeout

```
if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
  //time out error here
}
```

[image]

[image]

It was working fine, But I change timeout time by changing the default value from 1 minute to 1:30 minute, then problem appears. AFURLConnectionOperation file showing error

Use of undeclared identifier 'NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey'

That affected my all afneworking related project. I changed library files but things are same.
Help me, Any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve it by removing the derived data for xcode.,
go to

> xcode prefrence -> Locations -> derived data

1. now open derived data in finder
2. force close the xcode
3. force close the simulator
4. clear all derived data
5. relaunch your XCode project

   the problem might be solved in the case if you have not deleted any iOS framework

Comment: Thanks Er. Khatri, But my issue is still sustaining. Files are showing error,
Use of undeclared identifier 'NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey' in AFURLConnectionOperation. I am not able to run my project. Can you help me?

Comment: try clean the project and re build, as it work fine for me, or send me this class so that i can check

Comment: Er. Khatri, I m not sure what is going on,after cleaning previous error vanished, and a new one appears on NSURLErrorBadURL

Comment: i think something is fishy in xcode or any of the framework is missing...

Comment: open xcode prefrence from there you can get path of derived data for xcode, now open that folder in finder and force close xcode then delete the derived data content in finder.. now relaunch the xcode &now  you might get the exact error where code breaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156621/discussion-between-er-khatri-and-udai-kumar).